# Why doea $IFS act as a whitespace in the command "ls$ISF-l" but not "Echo hello"?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

`ls -l` has the same output as `ls$ISF-l`, but `echo$IFShello` does not have the same output as `echo hello`.

I'm aware that `$IFS` by default is equal to white space. I'm just wondering why `$IFS` is behaving differently in between these two scenario.

Peace.

Comment: What are the different outputs? try piping to `hd` or `od -c`. Salaam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Case "echo$IFShello" there is no Variable with name "IFShello".
You need "echo${IFS}hello" the get the same output as "echo hello"

Comment: Thanks! Novice mistake. I should have known better.